# Does the "forever" daemon cache the Node.js script?

Tags: node.js

Does the "[forever](https://github.com/indexzero/forever)" daemon know if I updated my Node.js script?

Is it safe for me to change my Node.js script if the forever daemon is actively running in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a definite answer (I have no clue) but merely a hint, have you checked the `watch`-settings?

From the `README` on github:

```
//
// Options for restarting on watched files.
//
'watch': false              // Value indicating if we should watch files.
'watchIgnoreDotFiles': null // Dot files we should read to ignore ('.foreverignore', etc).
'watchIgnorePatterns': null // Ignore patterns to use when watching files.
'watchDirectory': null      // Top-level directory to watch from.
```

Edit: So, guessing from these options, it probably does "cache" the script, in the sense that it reads its source once - unless you tell it to *watch* the source.